# Upper and Lower Error Bar at Confidence Level 68.3% for number of count is 500

Tags: poisson

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson

# Parameters
N = 500  # Poisson parameter
confidence_level = 0.683  # Desired confidence level (68.3%)

# Calculate the upper and lower errors
lower_error = poisson.ppf((1 - confidence_level) / 2, N)
upper_error = poisson.ppf(1 - (1 - confidence_level) / 2, N)

# Print results
print(f"Parameter (N): {N}")
print(f"Lower Error: {lower_error:.2f}")
print(f"Upper Error: {upper_error:.2f}")
```

I am trying to find upper and lower error bar using poisson distribution at confidence level 68.3%. The number of counts(N)= 500. I have written a python code. Not sure if it is producing a correct result or not. Can somebody please provide opinion. Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `poisson.ppf` with a distribution where you know the answers, such as normal. That will tell you if your approach is correct.

Comment: or try with smaller numbers where you can perform the calculation by hand